# Sampling VAE latent variables appropriately

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras

I am currently trying to create a variational autoencoder (VAE), that is trained on data that has been scaled to min/max (zero to one)The overall architecture can be seen below:. [image]

I'm in interested in sampling the learned latent space after it has been trained sufficiently. The latent space has size 200, so I figured I could create sample vectors doing the following:

```py
NUM_SAMPLED_VECTORS = 100
sampled_latent = []
max_latent_values = encoded_latent_df.max(axis=0).values.tolist()

# Sample 100 vectors 
for x in range(NUM_SAMPLED_VECTORS):
    temp = []
    for i,z in enumerate(max_latent_values):
        temp.append(uniform(0, z))
    sampled_latent.append(temp)

sampled_latent_df = pandas.DataFrame(sampled_latent)
sampled_pred_vectors = pd.DataFrame(decoder.predict_on_batch(sampled_latent_df))
```

Here, I'm randomly sampling the min/max range of each latent variable sequentially, and then predicting on that "sampled latent vector".

However, when I look at the output vectors, they are all off by a factor of ~10^30. I would expect that the output vectors would have values that are ~0.5 (e.g. between 0 and 1), but all predicted vectors have values of ~10^-30 (yes, larger than zero but barely at all). Is there a better way to sample the latent space so as to get appropriate sampled values?

Comment: what happens if you sample at 0? Do you also get tiny values? Typically in VAEs you should have most of the samples close to 0, are the max values perhaps outliers? Try plotting the overall distribution of latents and see where max is relative to this? If you wanted to sample, you should also sample the entire space also uniform(min_latent_values,max_latent_values) bcs min will almost certainly be below 0

Comment: Indeed, there is a "bimodal" distribution of the latent space values; one peak at (near) zero, and the other (near) one.  I haven't checked _every_ node, but I presume its the same for all of them. Sampling at/near zero (or just [0,1]) does indeed produce values in magnitude closer to what I would expect.

Is there a way to "link" the sampling of one node to another? I feel like randomly sampling [0,1] for each one throws out the paired learning of each node with each other.

Comment: Glad that helped :). Is there a reason you can't sample the actual data? Alternatively, its a bit crude, but depending on the application but you could just run PCA over the dimensions of the latent space for all examples and then collect samples by tiling the first n principal components and projecting this back into the latent space.

Comment: The reasons for not sampling the data directly are a bit convoluted, but essentially I would like to know what happens when you modulate specific values in the input vector (e.g. tuning down X%) and what happens to the rest of the values in my "input" vector; we don't necessarily have enough data that allows to sample those values specifically in the range we care about.

Comment: The latent space of a VAE is generally designed to be Gaussian normal (mean 0, std 1, the KL divergence does this), so it makes no sense to talk about a bimodal latent space or to sample it as uniform.